# Fallback solution for HTML <audio> and legacy browsers

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, html5-audio

I am working on creating a sound board with various audio clips.

Rather than using the standard HTML5 audio controls, I want to style each button with some title text, so that when a user presses a button, the associated clip plays.

Everything is working fine in HTML 5 browsers (Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and IE9+), using the following code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
       $(function() {
            $("audio").removeAttr("controls").each(function(i, audioElement) {
                var audio = $(this);
                var that = this; //closure to keep reference to current audio tag
                $("#doc").append($('<button>'+audio.attr("title")+'</button>').click(function() {
                    that.play();
                }));
            });
        });
    </script>

    <!-- Sample Audio Clip -->
    <audio controls preload="auto" autobuffer title="Sounds of Laughter"> 
    <source src="assets/clips/1.mp3" />
    <source src="assets/clips/1.ogg" />
    </audio>
```

However, this solution is not supported on non-HTML 5 compliant browsers like Internet Explorer 8.

I am looking for some sort of workaround solution that will allow me to either (a) detect if a browser doesn't support the HTML 5  tag and redirect to an alternate version of the sound board or (b) use a fallback (flash, etc.) with custom styling on the button if  support is not present.

Answer (score 2):

You should use both [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) as Garret said and [jPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org)

Check Garrett's answer on how to check for compatibility. Though I don't see why it would be useful if your only goal is to seamlessly play HTML5 or Flash based on compatibility. jPlayer does it automatically.

You just have to instantiate it:

```
$("#music").jPlayer({
    ready: function (event) {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3:"music.mp3",
            oga:"music.ogg"
        });
    },
    swfPath: "js",
    supplied: "mp3, oga"
});
```

The following depends on the interface you want to use. jPlayer has some skins, but you can modify them to your will or just create a whole interface from scratch like I do and use jPlayer methids

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) script library. This will allow you to perform conditional logic based on what HTML5 features are supported by the browser.  For example, you could do something like this:

```
var audio = new Audio();
audio.src = Modernizr.audio.ogg ? 'background.ogg' :
            Modernizr.audio.mp3 ? 'background.mp3' :
                                  'background.m4a';
audio.play();
```

Documentation can be found here: http://modernizr.com/docs/#features-html5.

Answer (score 0):

I found [another example](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FallbackHTML5AudioTagsForASimpleMP3PodcastAreHarderThanYoudThink.aspx) which I have slightly modified for MP3 to OGG fallback. It uses the `canPlayType` method:

```
var audiofile = 'example.mp3';
var audioTag = document.createElement('audio');
if (!(!!(audioTag.canPlayType) && ("no" != audioTag.canPlayType("audio/mpeg"))
      && ("" != audioTag.canPlayType("audio/mpeg")))) {
    audiofile = audiofile.replace('.mp3','.ogg');
}
```