# Play HTML audio in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, audio

I have this html and js which I'm using to play some audio:

HTML

```
<div id="audio-clips">
    <audio src="/audio/cha-ching.wav" type="audio/wav" id="audio-cha-ching">
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var sfx = $("#audio-clips #audio-cha-ching")[0];
sfx.play();
```

This is failing in IE 8, due to it not recognising the "play" method.  Is there a jQuery audio-playing method which works cross-browser, with the same code?  I'd rather do that then try to fall back to some IE-specific solution (as browser-specific solutions are always brittle).

Comment: As far as I have read in various blogs , the only way to make audio work in IE8 is to have a flash fallback.
You could try http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/ which provides a flash fallback when html audio is not supported

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly recommend using howler.js for playing audio files. It has great compatibility across browsers and devices. It uses HTML5 audio when available, and falls back to older technologies when necessary.

Comment: It doesn't support IE8, only IE9 and above.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 support on IE started on IE9 :(.

By the way, I am not sure if WAV is played by IE(I would not say so):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Audio

[Fallback solution for HTML  and legacy browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712363/fallback-solution-for-html-audio-and-legacy-browsers)

Comment: As you rightly said,according to the wiki link you provided , `IE` doesn't support `.wav` , it supports only `.mp3` and `.aac`

Comment: The WAV format is supported by many browsers, including IE9+. http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/adding-audio-with-the-new-html5-audio-tag

Comment: @Sohnee yeah,but not by `IE` and `opera`

Comment: IE: "Suitable audio formats are .mp3, .wav and .ogg." http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/adding-audio-with-the-new-html5-audio-tag Opera is also able to play wav.

Comment: Opera: "Opera 10.50 on Windows and Mac support the Ogg container format and the Theora and Vorbis codecs, as well as the WAVE container format and PCM codec." http://my.opera.com/core/blog/2010/03/03/everything-you-need-to-know-about-html5-video-and-audio-2

Answer (score 1):

The `audio` tag is available in Internet Explorer 9 and above. You can check this using [Can I Use - Audio](http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio).

The `wav` format is supported by Firefox 3.6+, Safari 5+, Opera 10.5+ and Internet Explorer 9+ on the audio tag. You would need to add an `MP3` source in addition to the `wav` source to get Chrome support.

To get backwards compatible support, you use the following - Flash element omitted for brevity.

```
<audio controls preload="auto" autobuffer> 
  <source src="sound.mp3" />
  <source src="sound.ogg" />
  <source src="sound.wav" />
  <!-- now include flash fall back -->
</audio>
```

Answer (score -5):

Encode your audio in mp4 format, instead of wav. This works for me in IE 11.