# Why isn't my JS audio button working in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, function, internet-explorer, onclick

I recently tried to make a basic webpage, which holds a button that when clicked, begins to play music from my local file. It work perfectly fine when in Chrome but won't work when in Internet Explorer.

Will include code below but unsure if I am missing some basic lines to make it compatible or whether there's a more underlying issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Audio Stream</title>
    <link href = "style.css" type = "text/css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <script src = "javascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id = "button" type = "button" onclick = 
    "testAudio('audio.mp3')">
    Test Audio
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Separate JS file.

```
function testAudio(path) {
    var audio = document.createElement('audio');
    audio.setAttribute('src', path);
    audio.play();
}
```

Comment: [Too much noise in post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: [Potential dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12894720/5267751). (i.e., if your IE version is <9, it won't work)

Comment: @user202729 Saying thanks twice?

Comment: @user202729 Okay, I'll take a look at that. Thanks!